# Why does initializing a class with a ternary if cause a double-free?

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, clang++

When the following code is compiled using clang with the clang-analyzer enabled:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Buffer {
    unsigned char *buf;
    Buffer() : buf(0) {}
    Buffer(const Buffer &that) {
        buf = new unsigned char;
        *buf = *that.buf;
    }
    Buffer(Buffer &&);
    ~Buffer() { delete buf; }
    Buffer &operator=(const Buffer &that) = delete;
    Buffer &operator=(Buffer &&that) = delete;
};

Buffer func() {
    Buffer a;
    return a;
}

int main() { Buffer a = 1 ? func() : Buffer(); }
```

Using the command:

```
scan-build clang++ main.cc -std=c++17
```

The following error is produced:

```
main.cc:10:17: warning: Attempt to free released memory
    ~Buffer() { delete buf; }
```

However, when initializing `a` with `Buffer a = func();` (without the ternary if) the error disappears. In addition, using `-std=c++11` also makes the error diappear.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I wonder what happens when that.buf is nullptr, and the code does `*buf = *that.buf;`

Comment: @Eljay I had a few checks such as ensuring that.buf is not null but removed them to simplify the question. The error still showed even with those checks.

Comment: I'm not getting the warning you are getting.  I'm using clang 10.0.0.  What version of clang are you using?

Comment: I'm on clang 7.0.1 but I'll give it a try with 10.

Comment: I tried it with clang 10 and didn't get the error. This seems like its a bug on the clang end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is ill-formed because the move constructor is used, but not defined which violates the One Definition Rule. The scanner diagnostic may be false positive caused by this bug in the program.

The copy constructor is not used, but it is broken because it potentially indirects through a null pointer.